# properties order in .Xresources

Tags: xorg, xterm

This drives me crazy... Maybe someone has an idea. I could not find something concerning exactly this.

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 (studio version) and have a .Xresources to set some nord theme based colors for my beloved xterm.
Looks like this:

```
XTerm*termName:    xterm-256color
#define nord0 #2E3440
...
*.color0: nord1
...
```

When I load (not merge yet) this with xrdb and start xterm, it all looks fine.

However after login, it does not...

Interrestingly, the resources are all here:

```
$ xrdb -query
*.background:   nord0
*.color0:       nord1
...
*.cursorColor:  nord4
*.foreground:   nord4
*customization: -color
XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  Yaru
```

The suspicious thing is the termNAme property which is located after the colors. Not sure if there is some ordering?

When I load it again, xterm has the wanted colors again. 
*But*, the query result is a bit different:

```
$ xrdb -query
XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
*.background:   #2E3440
*.foreground:   #D8DEE9
*.cursorColor:  #D8DEE9
*.color0:       #3B4252
*.color1:       #BF616A
...
```

Now the termNAme property is at the beginning, as it is in the .Xresources file, as well as the other color properties.

So why is this different after login?
My only conlcusion is, that something influences the order or does whatever in the login process.
I could not yet figure out what really happens here. I'm sure I overlooked something that is too close ;)

Does anyone know something about this behaviour?
Thank you very much so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found a solution, when I coincidentally tried Wayland as displaymanager.
Using this, the colours in xterm are correct after login.
The customization property (and also others) are not there, so I assume that there aren't any default xrdb properties loaded, just mine.

In the end I'm happy now.

Maybe this might help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually because of the line

```
*customization: -color
```

This property is added (at least on Ubuntu 20.04) in `/etc/X11/Xresources/x11-common`.

You may verify this by dumping all the properties after login to some file:

```
xrdb -query -all > /tmp/xrdb.res
```

Remove the above line `*customization: -color` and use `load` by issuing

```
xrdb -load /tmp/xrdb.res
```

However, the only workaround I found until now (`xrdb -remove` doesn't work in my custom script running on login) is to have the properties duplicated in `~/.Xresources` like this:

```
*color0: black
*VT100*color0: black
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. 
Good point! And yes, after load that property diesppeared.